# Script on Perl doesn't work. Apache gave me 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, perl, phpmyadmin

So. I check my script

```
perl -cw /var/www/cgi/env.pl
var/www/cgi/env.pl syntax OK
```

I double check it in commandline. It works and shows me my environment values.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com` looks like this:

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.com

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi/

<Directory "/var/www/cgi">
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

It should work, but i've got 500 error.
Apache log says:

```
[Fri Sep 19 09:29:04 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi/env.pl' failed
[Fri Sep 19 09:29:04 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: env.pl
```

What should I do to make it work?
Is it possible that `phpmyadmin` influent to apache server like this. I do `not use php` except phpmyadmin for database. Maybe here is the problem?

Comment: Check the script's #!shebang

Comment: @Miller i used `whereis perl` and check it, it's fine

Comment: Good point, ftp in text mode any text files from Windows to Linux or Unix. And view source code for a second with view - b filename

Answer (score 0):

Okay.
This is my mistake.
This script was written on Windows machine and I forget about this fact for a while.
So I tried to delete carriage return symbol.
Now my script works.

Solution is:
`perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g /path/to/your/script'`

Comment: Some folks do the same thing with `dos2unix`.  That way you even clean up any EOF markers.